# C++ arrays, expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

Ok, so I am new to coding and am trying to learn c++. I am making a program to verify a password has uppercase, lowercase, and a number. I feel that the solution will be a simple one but I cannot for the life of me work it out.

```
using namespace std;

    string password ="";
    cin >> password;
```

I can validate this fine. I then want to convert the password to an array of chars so I can check each character of the password. I start with:

```
    char passwordHolder[password.length()];
```

but I get the error:

> expression must have a constant value

From looking at other forum responses I think it has something to do with visual studio as a compiler not being able to handle variable arrays, though I don't really understand how/why this happens, or how to work around this.

Another post suggests using the `new` operator but I don't understand fully how to implement this into my code in a way that works.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `char passwordHolder[password.length()];` tries to allocate an array of chars with a non `const` value. C++ doesn't support variable length arrays. Use a `std::vector<char> passwordHolder(password.length());` instead.

Comment: Side note: The `string` contains an array of characters. You probably don't need a new one. Waltz though the `string` with `password[index]`, iterators, or a range-based for loop. If you want to really show off, there's probably something in the [algorithm library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that will do the bulk of the heavy lifting for you (hint: There is).

Comment: `char passwordHolder[password.length()];` is a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and C++ doesn't have those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I finally got it. Thanks to user4581301 for telling me that a string already is an array of characters. This hint gave me ideas of how to solve the problem.

I actually managed to get rid of the new array entirely and instead search through the string.

instead of `char passwordHolder[password.length()];` I could get rid of that entirely.

My initial plan was to search the `passwordHolder` array with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
  if (isupper(passwordHolder[i])){
    hasUpper= true;
  }
  if (islower(passwordHolder[i])){
    hasLower= true;
  }
  if (isdigit(passwordHolder[i])){
    hasDigit = true;
  }
}
if (hasLower == true && hasUpper == true && hasDigit == true)
        return 1;
```

but seeing as I no longer need the `passwordHolder` array, I could instead use `password` as the array and do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
        if (isupper(password[i]))
            hasUpper = true;
        else if (islower(password[i]))
            hasLower = true;
        else if (isdigit(password[i]))
            hasDigit = true;
    }
    if (hasLower == true && hasUpper == true && hasDigit == true)
        return 1;
```

Thank you to those who commented. I had been stuck on this for like 3 hours lol.

If you are also having issues with this task, my full solution is here. Probably still very scruffy but it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


string password = "";
string confirmPassword = "";

bool hasDigit = false;
bool hasUpper = false;
bool hasLower = false;

int x = 0;

int confirm(string password, bool hasUpper, bool hasLower, bool hasDigit)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {

        if (isupper(password[i]))
            hasUpper = true;
        else if (islower(password[i]))
            hasLower = true;
        else if (isdigit(password[i]))
            hasDigit = true;
    }
    if (hasLower == true && hasUpper == true && hasDigit == true)
        return 1;
}

int main(string password, bool hasUpper, bool hasLower, bool hasDigit) {

Start:

    cout << "please enter your password: ";
    cin >> password;
    cout << "please confirm your password: ";
    cin >> confirmPassword;

    while (password != confirmPassword || password.length() < 8) {

        cout << "Passwords do not match. Please enter your password again: ";
        cin >> password;
        cout << "Please confirm your password: ";
        cin >> confirmPassword;
    }
    
    x = confirm(password, hasUpper, hasLower, hasDigit);

    if (x == 1) {
        cout << "You have a good password";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You should have a password with 8 characters or more, a Capital letter, lowercase letter, and a number. Try again. \n";
        goto Start;
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace the `goto` statements with a loop

Comment: Missing return statement will cause cause undefined values to be returned.

Comment: You are using c++11 or newer? `string` also has iterators, so you can replace the index-for-loop with an range-based-for-loop `for( char symbol : password)`, and replace `password[i]` with `symbol`.

Comment: @Phil1970 where do you mean I am missing a return statement? It seems to work as it is currently.